# Oracle - List every single day with hours in the month

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, recursive-query

I do some dashboard and I found out that I dont have any table including all the dates I need. My subqueries are made to be connect by DATE (DD.MM,YYYY) and HOURS (HH24). However I got stuck with the template.

I listed all days in the month via

```
select to_date('1.' || to_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM.YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy') + level - 1 as month
   from dual
  connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate), 'DD')
```

and also listed all Hours for day via

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1 / 24*(level - 1)
   from dual
  connect by level <= 24
```

When I combine it with rownum = 1 in month so I get only 1 day it works...

```
select to_date(to_char(mesic, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1 / 24*(level - 1)
   from 
(select *
           from (select to_date('1.' || to_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM.YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy') + level - 1 as mesic
                   from dual
                  connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate), 'DD'))
          where rownum = 1)

  connect by level <= 24
```

However when I erase the rownum condition I got eror that I got maximum rows.

By my logic it should be like 24 (hours)*31 (days in current month) = 744. My casual dashborads reports have often like 5000 rows so this should not be a problem.

Thank you for advices guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks as simple as

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + (level - 1) / 24 datum
from dual
connect by level <= (add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 1) - trunc(sysdate, 'mm')) * 24;

DATUM
----------------
01.08.2020 00:00
01.08.2020 01:00
01.08.2020 02:00
<snip>
31.08.2020 21:00
31.08.2020 22:00
31.08.2020 23:00

744 rows selected.
```

Comment: @DominikVana . . . If this (or the other answer) answers your question, then you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate all hours in the current month, you can do:

```
with cte (dt) as (
    select trunc(sysdate, 'month') from dual
    union all
    select dt + interval '1' hour 
    from cte 
    where dt + interval '1' hour < trunc(sysdate, 'month') + interval '1' month
)
select * from cte
```

We can reduce the number of iterations by generating the days and hours separatly, then cross-joining them:

```
with 
    days (dy) as (
        select trunc(sysdate, 'month') from dual
        union all
        select dy + interval '1' day 
        from days 
        where dy + interval '1' day < trunc(sysdate, 'month') + interval '1' month
    ),
    hours (hh) as (
        select 0 from dual
        union all 
        select hh + 1 from hours where hh < 23
    )
select d.dy + h.hh  * interval '1' hour dt
from days d
cross join hours h
```